# How to get Casting Device Icon and convert it as Image or BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, win-universal-app, device

I like to get `casting device icon` and display it on screen. But I do not have any clue how to do this. `CastingDevice.Icon` is possible to read as `Stream` (somehow) but how to read it if I want that result is `Image` or `BitmapImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CastingDevice.Icon is possible to read as Stream (somehow) but how to read it if I want that result is Image or BitmapImage?

You could use the [SetSourceAsync(IRandomAccessStream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_BitmapSource_SetSourceAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_)
 method of BitmapImage to create a BitmapImage object, then you could use this BitmapImage as Image's Source.

Comment: Thanks a lot Xavier Xie!  Much easier than I ever believed.